# Invoking http adapter procedure failure

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm trying to send some values to a web server and it is going to respond with true or false using http adapter in ibm mobilefirst. When i invoke the procedure from the environment, i got this error:

```
{
"errors": [
  "Runtime: Http request failed: java.net.UnknownHostException: mfpreader.comze.com\/"
],
"info": [
],
"isSuccessful": false,
"warnings": [
]
}
```

Here is the link i'm using:
http://mfpreader.comze.com/login.php?username=kevin&password=pass
The server is working.

**LoginAdapter.xml**

```
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>https</protocol>
        <domain>mfpreader.comze.com/</domain>
        <port>443</port>        


<procedure name="getVerify"/>
```

**LoginAdapter-impl.js**

```
                 function getVerify(pName) {

var input = {
    method : 'get',
    returnedContentType : 'json',
    path : '/login.php',
    parameters : {
        'username' : pName,
        'password' : 'pass'   // hard-coded
            }

 };

return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);

}
```

Can i have some help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

connect website using **http** port **80** .on the other hand return  `returnedContentType : 'plain'` .

### LoginAdapter.xml

```
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>http</protocol>
            <domain>mfpreader.comze.com</domain>

            <port>80</port>      


<procedure name="getVerify"/>
```

### LoginAdapter-impl.js

```
function getVerify(pName) {

    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'plain',
        path : '/login.php',
        parameters : {
            'username' : pName,
            'password' : 'pass'   // hard-coded
                }

     };

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);

    }
```

### invocation result:

```
{
   "errors": [
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "responseHeaders": {
      "Connection": "close",
      "Content-Length": "748",
      "Content-Type": "text\/html",
      "Date": "Fri, 19 Feb 2016 11:56:31 GMT",
      "Server": "Apache",
      "X-Powered-By": "PHP\/5.2.17"
   },
   "responseTime": 563,
   "statusCode": 200,
   "statusReason": "OK",
   "text": "<br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'><b>PHP Error Message<\/b><\/font><\/td><\/tr><\/table><br \/>\n<b>Warning<\/b>:  json_encode() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in <b>\/home\/a1974455\/public_html\/login.php<\/b> on line <b>72<\/b><br \/>\n<br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><div align='center'><a href='http:\/\/www.000webhost.com\/'><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'>Free Web Hosting<\/font><\/a><\/div><\/td><\/tr><\/table> \n<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/stats.hosting24.com\/count.php\"><\/script>\n<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->",
   "totalTime": 578,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

Comment: {
   "errors": [
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "responseHeaders": {
      "Connection": "close",
      "Content-Length": "159",
      "Content-Type": "text\/html",
      "Date": "Sat, 20 Feb 2016 11:15:35 GMT",
      "Server": "Apache",
      "X-Powered-By": "PHP\/5.2.17"
   },
   "responseTime": 705,
   "statusCode": 200,
   "statusReason": "OK",
   "text": "True \n<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/stats.hosting24.com\/count.php\"><\/script>\n<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->",
   "totalTime": 706,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}

Comment: The above shows the results of your code. How to drill down and extract only the value from the "text": "True"??

Comment: I Suggest, you open a different question .

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you have a surplus `/` in your domain name:

```
<domain>mfpreader.comze.com/</domain>
```

This is a *domain name*, not a URL. You need to specify only the hostname of the server you are trying to reach:

```
<domain>mfpreader.comze.com</domain>
```

Comment: Thnk u andrew. Now, i got this error: Procedure invocation failed: Read timed out

Comment: That's a different issue. Suggest you open a different question.

Answer (score 0):

The website does not work.

When you pointed to it, you're using **http**, but in the XML you're using **https**. And when trying to access the website with the **https** protocol, it is not loading.

Comment: yes, u r rite. its http://mfpreader.comze.com/login.php?username=kevin&password=pass

Comment: I have changed the protocol from https to http in the xml file. i got the same error.

Comment: How to connect if the website is using http??