# Error in reading json response from http adapter

Tags: json

Referring to my previous post: 
[Invoking http adapter procedure failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502882/invoking-http-adapter-procedure-failure#)

After I receive the reponse from the webserver. I got the following error:

```
{
"errors": [
  "Runtime: Failed to read the HTTP response to: \/login.php?username=kevin&password=pass \nFailed to parse JSON string\n{\"True\":1} \n<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/stats.hosting24.com\/count.php\"><\/script>\n<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->"
],
"info": [
],
"isSuccessful": false,
"warnings": [
]
}
```

Can I have some help to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

Change the `returnedContentType` to "plain". This will make the server return the content as a big string and not attempt to parse it. Then in your adapter, you can use `var obj = JSON.parse(response.text)`.

Comment: i tried. I got this error:

   
      "Runtime: Failed to read the HTTP response to: \/login.php?username=kevin&password=pass \nFailed to parse JSON string\n<br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'><b>PHP Error Message<\/b><\/font><\/td><\/tr><\/table><br \/>\n<b>Fatal error<\/b>:  Call to undefined function  up_json_encode() in <b>\/home\/a1974455\/public_html\/login.php<\/b> on line <b>60<\/b><br \/>\n<br><

Comment: Okay. You're making helping you get hard without something that reproduces your problem.

Comment: "isSuccessful": true,
   "responseHeaders": {
      "Connection": "close",
      "Content-Length": "159",
      "Content-Type": "text\/html",
      "Date": "Sat, 20 Feb 2016 11:15:35 GMT",
      "Server": "Apache",
      "X-Powered-By": "PHP\/5.2.17"
   },
   "responseTime": 705,
   "statusCode": 200,
   "statusReason": "OK",
   "text": "True \n<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/stats.hosting24.com\/count.php\"><\/script>\n<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->",
   "totalTime": 706,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
How to get the value from the text true only??